# Range on a trigonometric function given domain

Tags: calculus

I have a function: 
$h(x)=-sin(\frac{4 \pi x}{3})$

Range is given by:
$R_h=\{h(a):a\in D_h\}$

And domain is given by:
$D_h \in Z$

So the questions is: How do I prove that there is exactly three solutions?
I tried some values:

$R_h=\{\dots,h(-2),h(-1),h(0),h(1),h(2),\dots\}$

And it's not hard to see the pattern. 
I also know that the function is periodic with the period $\frac{3}{2}$

We have three cases for  $D_h \in Z$:

$h\rightarrow -sin(\frac{4 \pi }{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$h\rightarrow -sin(\frac{2 \pi }{3})=\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$h\rightarrow -sin(0)=0$

Answer: $R_h \in \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0\bigg)$

How would one go about and prove this?
Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $a\in D_h $.
There are three cases:

$$a=3k $$

$$a=3k+1$$

$$a=3k+2$$
for some $k\in \Bbb Z $.

For example, if $a=3k+1$, then
$$h (a)=\sin (\frac {4\pi (3k+1)}{3}) $$
$$=\sin (4k\pi+\frac {4\pi}{3}) $$
$$=\sin (\pi+\frac {\pi}{3}) $$
$$=-\sin (\frac {\pi}{3})=-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}$$